# How to make my program work with the latest boost library

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, cmake

I have compiled a C++ program that need `libboost-system1.46`. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 so I have `libboost-system1.54`. When I run the program it says that `libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1` was not found. How can I (if it is possible) to make the program work with `libboost-system1.54`. Perhaps there's a place where we specify which version to use. Is what I thinking is correct?

Comment: Recompile against newer libraries?

Comment: How? I used the script given with the program sources and I did that with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Just a guess, you should do a `make clean` and then make (i.e. rebuild the program), and everything should be fine.

Comment: @AdityaKumar I think it might fail with `cmake` as it likes to cache, the `find_package` results. If I recall correctly `make clean` does not clean cache. It all depends on the build system used, which is mysterious as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to recompile against the newer version of library. AFAIK boost libraries are not binary compatible between versions, so simple . You could do tricks, to use the other version (symbolic links or other magic), but it would most probably not work.

So you either need to provide the version that is required or change the requirement - recompilation.

If you wrote the program, or built it, you just need to repeat the whole build procedure, with all the configures before the `make` or compilation. Technically, just relinking should work, but some systems like CMake cache the configuration options evaluated at this step, and simply, calling `make` again would not work. So I would suggest to repeat whole process.

Whatever the procedure looked, it should suffice just to repeat it.

Comment: My problem was that the program I use call other programs that were compiled under the 1.46 version. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score -2):

You may be able to create a symbolic link which points the name libboost-system1.46 to libboost-system1.54.

This will work as long as the interfaces for the functionality you're using hasn't changed, though is probably not a good idea.  It may work just get your code going and tested, but would never be appropriate for any sort of release software.

You should try to recompile your program with the newer version of boost.

Comment: that is just a bad advice.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the versions are binary compatible ?

Comment: Then this is a truly horrific idea and you should be taken out and shot for even thinking about recommending it.